# Como fazer mudanças em um usurious cadastrado com o método PUT?

Tags: javascript, api, express.js, postman, nodemon

Ola estou aprendo javaScript, agora no back-end montei uma API de cadastro de usuário Email,Nome,Idade,Telefone. usei o método POST para inserir o novo usuário no array e o GET para mostrar os usuários, até ai tudo tranquilo. Agora queria fazer mudanças em um usuário cadastrado com o PUT, to travado kk

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de código para update utilizando o mongodb. Mas esta mesma lógica pode ser utilizada para banco de dados relacionais.

***usuario.route.js***

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/user.controller');
//...
router.put('/users/:id', userController.updateUserbyId);
//...
module.exports = router;
```

***usuario.controller.js***

```
exports.updateUserbyId = (req, res) => {
    const options = { returnOriginal: false };
    db.get().collection('user').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, {$set: {"name": req.body.name }}, options).then((result) => {
        if (result.value === null) {
            return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
        }
        res.status(200).json(result.value);
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({errors: [{location: "users", msg: err, param: req.params.id}]})
    })
}
```

Recomendo também fazer a validação da entrada antes de fazer a inserção no banco de dados.